# Dealing with a JSON object too big to fit into memory

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, firebase, jsonstream

I have a dump of a Firebase database representing our Users table stored in JSON. I want to run some data analysis on it but the issue is that it's too big to load into memory completely and manipulate with pure JavaScript (or `_` and similar libraries).

Up until now I've been using the [JSONStream](https://github.com/dominictarr/JSONStream) package to deal with my data in bite-sized chunks (it calls a callback once for each user in the JSON dump).

I've now hit a roadblock though because I want to *filter* my user ids based on their value. The "questions" I'm trying to answer are of the form "Which users x" whereas previously I was just asking "How many users x" and didn't need to know who they were.

The data format is like this:

```
{
    users: {
        123: {
            foo: 4
        },
        567: {
            foo: 8
        }
    }
}
```

What I want to do is essentially get the user ID (`123` or `567` in the above) based on the value of `foo`. Now, if this were a small list it would be trivial to use something like `_.each` to iterate over the keys and values and extract the keys I want.

Unfortunately, since it doesn't fit into memory that doesn't work. With JSONStream I can iterate over it by using `var parser = JSONStream.parse('users.*');` and piping it into a function that deals with it like this:

```
var stream = fs.createReadStream('my.json');

stream.pipe(parser);

parser.on('data', function(user) {
    // user is equal to { foo: bar } here
    // so it is trivial to do my filter
    // but I don't know which user ID owns the data
});
```

But the problem is that I don't have access to the key representing the star wildcard that I passed into `JSONStream.parse`. In other words, I don't know if `{ foo: bar}` represents user `123` or user `567`.

The question is twofold:

1. **How can I get the current path from within my callback?**
2. Is there a better way to be dealing with this JSON data that is too big to fit into memory?

Comment: 1. You can't, at all. Will never happen (using your current structure). Why not put this JSON into an actual database (MySQL, for instance) and actually query it to do your analytics?

Comment: Can't what? Is there something that makes accessing the path technically less feasible than the data?

Comment: In your callback, as you are figuring out, there is no `path`, there is only data. You have no context and a "child" object from a JSON string has no concept of where it came from.

Comment: I would run into the same issue putting it into MySQL I believe, I'd need to use JSONStream to parse it (since it still doesn't fit into memory) and would need the user ID to store it into the relational database.

Comment: Two questions - 1) Why don't you have access to the * key and 2) What kind of memory do you have available to you/how big is the file? If it got dumped from a database, then it surely can get imported into one. - My bad, I just noticed how the * key worked in JSON stream and now I understand.

Comment: It looks like this is a limitation of JSONStream currently, I went ahead and modified it to provide the key as well as the data, posting an answer now in case anyone else ever encounters this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I went ahead and edited JSONStream to add this functionality.

If anyone runs across this and wants to patch it similarly, you can replace `line 83` which was previously

```
stream.queue(this.value[this.key])
```

with this:

```
var ret = {};
ret[this.key] = this.value[this.key];

stream.queue(ret);
```

In the code sample from the original question, rather than `user` being equal to `{ foo: bar }` in the callback it will now be `{ uid: { foo: bar } }`

Since this is a breaking change I didn't submit a pull request back to the original project but I did leave it in the issues in case they want to add a flag or option for this in the future.

Comment: One way you could also implement this is to maintain on each iteration the current path, so that you can also return a string containing the full path of the JSON object, instead of returning only the last key name.

Comment: Yeah I think that would probably be preferred. I'm wasn't familiar enough with Node's Stream class to figure out how to do this but ideally the callback would take 2 parameters, the first being the data, and the second being an array of the path segments needed to reach it in the original JSON (eg ['users', '123']). That'd let you easily get things like the current depth, any number of wildcards, etc.

Comment: Looks like my suggestion isn't realistic though, as JSONStream is… a stream, the `data` handler must only manage one parameter, not two. One way to circumvent this is to return an object `{value: {...}, path: ''}`, but this would break backwards compatibility.