# Process large array of objects in JSON file

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, node.js, stream

I have an extremely large array of objects stored in a JSON file, which I would like to process and update. The array contains millions of objects. Normally, I would have used `JSON.parse()` followed by something like

```
Promise.map(arr, someFunction)
.map(obj => anotherFunction)
.then(arr => console.log('Done.'));
```

However, the JSON file cannot be loaded into memory all at once. So how can I reduce memory usage? I was thinking of processing them with Nodejs streams, so I could process it a bit at a time. I will also need to add or remove properties of some objects.

Comment: Take a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20690203/dealing-with-a-json-object-too-big-to-fit-into-memory

Comment: Put the data in a database and then query that - let someone else do the heavy lifting.

Comment: Agree with @Cynigo. Stream is way to go.

Comment: React (RxJS) is also fun to play with for "streams".